# Fixing javascript array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to initialize an array with another array.  The array contains options for loading an RSS feed reader.  The user clicks an option button to selection which RSS category to read.  Based on the selection I initalize the feed URL and options arrays like this.

```
feeds = feedsnews.slice(0, feedsnews.length);
options = optionsnews.slice(0, optionsnews.length);
```

(The entire javascript for this is at the end of the text).
Then I send these arrays to the code for loading the newsreader. This seems to initialize only the first element in the array.

What is the way to initialize the array with all the elements?  Are the arrays declared in the right way for the RSS loader to get them?

Here is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

      var feedsnews = [ {title: 'Reuters Top News', url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews' }, {title: 'Reuters International', 
url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/worldNews' }, {title: 'Reuters US News', url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/domesticNews' }];
      var optionsnews = {
        stacked : true,
        horizontal : false,
        title : "News"
      }

      var feedscat = [ {title: 'Catholic News Agency', url: 'http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/rss/news.xml' }, {title: 'Zenit - English', url: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenit/english' }, {title: 'Zenit - Français', url: 
'http://feeds.feedburner.com/zenit/french' }];
      var optionscat = {
        stacked : true,
        horizontal : false,
        title : "Catholic"
      }

</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var feeds=feedsnews.slice();
var options=optionsnews.slice();

function GetSelectedItem() {

   feeds=feedsnews.slice(0, feedsnews.length);
   options=optionsnews.slice(0, optionsnews.length);

   chosen = "";
   len = document.f1.r1.length;

   for (i = 0; i <len; i++) {
     if (document.f1.r1[i].checked) {
     chosen = document.f1.r1[i].value
     }
   }

   if (chosen == "") {
     alert("No Location Chosen")
   }
   else if (chosen =="News") {
     feeds = feedsnews.slice(0,feedsnews.length);
     options = optionsnews.slice(0,optionsnews.length);
   }
   else if (chosen =="Catholic") {
     feeds = feedscat.slice(0,feedscat.length);
     options = optionscat.slice(optionscat.length);
   }
   else if (chosen =="Community") {

   }
   else if (chosen =="Personal") {

   }
   else if (chosen =="Professional") {

   }
   else {
     alert(chosen);
   }

   $("#snews").load("loadnews.php");

}
</script>

HTML (for #snews div)

    <div id="snews" style="position:absolute; top:30px; right: 30px; width: 430px; height: 380px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; background: white;">

         <?php require("loadnews.php"); ?>

    </div> <!-- End snews -->


PHP (loadnews.php)

<!-- ++Begin Dynamic Feed Wizard Generated Code++ -->
  <!--
  // Created with a Google AJAX Search and Feed Wizard
  // http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/wizards.html
  -->

  <!--
  // The Following div element will end up holding the actual feed control.
  // You can place this anywhere on your page.
  -->
  <div id="feed-control">
    <span style="color:#676767;font-size:11px;margin:10px;padding:4px;">Loading...</span>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadDynamicFeedControl() {

      new GFdynamicFeedControl(feeds, 'feed-control', options);
    }
    // Load the feeds API and set the onload callback.
    google.load('feeds', '1');
    google.setOnLoadCallback(LoadDynamicFeedControl);
  </script>

<!-- ++End Dynamic Feed Control Wizard Generated Code++ -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var optionsnews = {
    stacked : true,
    horizontal : false,
    title : "News"
  }

// snip...

options=optionsnews.slice(0, optionsnews.length);
```

`optionsnews` is an `Object`, not an `Array`. There is no `Object.slice` method since objects have neither numerical indexing nor inherent ordering.

What is the point of all this `.slice()`ing? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said I am trying to copy arrays into arrays, for the options an object into an object. Then I send the copy to a function to show the RSS feeds based on the user selection.

Comment: What is the point of the copying? Why copy at all? Why not just pass `feedsnews` and `optionsnews` directly? General-purpose object graph copying/cloning in JavaScript is not easy or simple.

Comment: Copying because the feeds array will depend on the user selection.  I have a feeds array and an options object as variables to pass the selection to a function.

Comment: To be frank, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why isn't `if (chosen =="News") { feeds = feedsnews; options = optionsnews; }` (etc.) sufficient?

Comment: Either way, you can't copy an object using `slice`.